# FFmpeg overlay filter_complex is slow on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg on Android (Xamarin) to add a watermark to a video. I have tested the operation with multiple videos and i think overall performance is pretty bad. I wanted to share my results and see how if anyone has similar or better benchmarks.

I'm using the following command for adding a png watermark to the video.

```
$"-i {video} -i {watermark} -filter_complex \"overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5\" -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -loglevel debug {output} -y";
```

The watermark is a 150x150 png with a filesize of 18KB.

Video 1
 - 13 seconds
 - 3840x2160
 - 60FPS
 - 125MB
**FFmpeg duration: 156 seconds**

Video 2
 - 4 seconds
 - 3840x2160
 - 30FPS
 - 17MB
**FFmpeg duration: 35 seconds**

Video 3
 - 10 seconds
 - 1920x1080
 - 60FPS
 - 35MB
**FFmpeg duration: 79 seconds**

What do you think of these results, is it legit that adding an overlay takes that long? Maybe there is something wrong with my command? I ran these tests on an Asus Zenfone 6 (Snapdragon 855, 8GB RAM)

EDIT:
I'm using FFmpeg version 3.0.1.1 compiled for ARM. (https://github.com/gperozzo/XamarinAndroidFFmpeg/tree/master/binary/3.0.1.1/arm).

All videos are mp4 files with the H.264 format.

Comment: You can enable "Show CPU Usage" within the developer options to confirm that the cpu is max'd, but based upon the resolution you are converting, the times are not totally out of line for software-based decode/overlay/encode an ARM cpu. Of course I do not know the type of codec(s) that your vids are using, nor which options your ffmpeg was compiled with, etc...

Comment: thank you for the comment, i added some more information regarding ffmpeg and codecs to my question. I also inspected CPU usage during the process of decode/overlay/encode and noticed that it's only somewhere in the range of 5% - 12% seems kinda weird 

Comment: That is a really old version of ffmpeg (personally I would cross-compile a newer version), but again I do not know if that particular ffmpeg was compiled w/ support for `MediaCodec` (the only supported "-hwaccel" codec for 264, device dependent of course), but that is for decode only, 264 encoding will be via "software". Now OpenCL for hardware accel-based filter can be used (Google does not support it in the OS) and thus is dependent upon SoC/OEM/3rd-parties to provide libraries and that makes it SoC dependent as not everyone uses the same GPU IP in their ARM SoCs.

Comment: thanks everyone for the input. I ended up binding RxFFmpeg for Xamarin.Android. They use an optimized compiled version with support for MediaCodec. I will put my bindings project on github